# Inconsistent Accessibility 2

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I've been searching for similar problems and looked on most of the similar problems but none of the answers were useful...

I get this error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'FinalProject.MySQL' is less accessible than method 'FinalProject.Form2.Form2(FinalProject.MySQL)'

```
namespace FinalProject
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection c;
        public Form2(MySqlConnection connection) //this is the line of the error.
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            c = connection;
        }

        private void okBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (c.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                textBox1.Text += "conection open";
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace FinalProject
{
    public class MySQL
    {
        public MySqlConnection connection;
        private string server;
        private string port;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;

        //Constructor
        public MySQL()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        //Initialize values
        private void Initialize()
        {
      .
      .
      .
```

I've tried to put the 'public' modifier on everything i can think of... no luck :)))

Comment: But the type of the parameter is `FinalProject.MySQLConnection`, not `FinalProject.MySQL`, and you haven't shown the definition of `FinalProject.MySQLConnection`.  Are you sure you made that type public as well?

Comment: MySQLConnection is from the MySQL library

Comment: Aha, I was thrown off by the "My" in "MySQLConnection" :(

Comment: Sorry... After some of the changes i didn't tried to build the solution... The error disappeared .. thanks

Comment: If you have found a solution kindly, post the answer, delete your question or edit your question (at the top to show its fixed so no other people waste there time). Thank you.